# Removing password for a excel file using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have multiple excel workbook send to me everyday with password protected. Our procedure requires me to remove the password and save it in share drive. I believe the password is added by the sender using below

```
workbook.saveas password:="pw"
```

i have tried `workbook.unprotect` or `workbook.saveas password:=""` but this fail to remove the password. anyone know how i can automate this instead of manually removing the password?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the password setting in the workbook before saving.

```
Option Explicit

Sub testPasswordRemoval()

    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="C:\Temp\Book2.xlsm", Password:="pw")
    wb.Password = ""
    wb.SaveAs "C:\Temp\NewBook.xlsm"

End Sub
```